# Including relationships in outbound messages

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

Is this even possible?

Example: `Department` is a Child of `Account`.

The UI Wizard only includes `Department` fields on outbound message selector.

Found this [link](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrCkAAK)

Is there a way to manually edit the outbound message definition to do this?

Answer (score 2):

No this is not currently possible, you'd have to use the option to send a sessionId in the message and have your listener make an API call back to saleforce to get the related records it needs.